# Is it better to declare a variable in python: = None, or = str(), or = ""?

Tags: python, scope, global-variables, variable-declaration

Is it better to declare a variable in python as None if you need to assign it later inside a different local area? I could not find the best practice on this:

1. if it is just going to be one string/int/boolean?
2. if it is going to be a list/tuple/dictionary?

Appreciate your advice!

```
def get_executed_list(list_of_strings):
    """list_of_strings is a list"""

    updated_list = None

    for single_string in list_of_strings:
        single_string += "-executed"
        updated_list.append(single_string)

    return updated_list
```

OR

```
def get_executed_list(list_of_strings):
    """list_of_strings is a list"""
    
    updated_list = []
    
    for single_string in list_of_strings:
        single_string += "-executed"
        updated_list.append(single_string)
    
    return updated_list
```

OR

```
def get_executed_list(list_of_strings):
    """list_of_strings is a list"""
    
    updated_list = ""
    
    for single_string in list_of_strings:
        single_string += "-executed"
        updated_list.append(single_string)
    
    return updated_list
```

Comment: Well, only one of these options *works*, so I'd go with that one unless your goal is to make code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out, only your second example actually works.

As for the question itself, I would only initialise a value to `None`, for then to later reinitialise it to the intended data type, if you actually need to distinguish between the two states.

An example use case for this is a class that is intended to hold data read from an external source like a file. Say a text file of name/value pairs. Since the `None` type in Python has an undefined value, it can be distinguished from for instance `0`, `""` or `[]` when these can represent valid value entries in your file. You can then check if you received your data and it was empty, or it was never seen at all.

Answer (score 1):

Most times, if you don't know which structure to use, you probably can't tell exactly what are your needs. A good way to tell what you need are the methods you'll be using. For example, you used the method append, which is a method for lists. So, your attempt to define `updated_list` as a None or as a string won't even work, because those don't have the append method.